# Button is not triggering in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to fix a bug I've encountered with a button not triggering in my webform.

The code for the button in the aspx file and the vb file looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUserEditSave" runat="server" Text="Save User" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="button saveButton xbtnWaitEvent" width="100px" ToolTip="Save changes" />
```

```vb
Protected Sub btnUserEditSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserEditSave.Click
```

I haven't included to code for the button itself as it's irrelevant because the bug relates to the button not triggering rather than the code of the button itself breaking. I've tested how the button works and what causes it to not trigger and here's the information I have thus far:

When first saving user details through this button, the button triggers and all code runs as expected. The page is the reloaded with the new user details showing.

However after doing this, the button will not trigger properly and when clicked will cause the page to go blank. This is despite the fact that no page load methods written in the source trigger either nor does the Javascript seem to either which I've tried testing through the use of alerts (see code below):

```cs
if(document.getElementById('btnUserEditSave').clicked == true)
{
    alert("button was clicked");
}
```

It is worth noting that the other buttons on the page also do not work again in a very similar way. The code behind the button does not trigger nor does a page load method trigger. But a blank page is still shown.

If any further code is needed for context then I will provide as much as I can, and any help as to what might be causing this error would be greatly appreciated as I am rather stuck for ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that javascript will actually do anything. Have you checked the console for errors? With errors like this, I always start by deleting the control (or commenting-out) and re-adding it. Sounds like there might be an issue in the code we can't see, since it works at least once.

Comment: @wazz what do you mean by deleting and re-adding the control? Do you mean the code behind the button itself or something else?

Comment: Yes, delete both the button on the .aspx page and the code behind, then re-add the button to check that everything is wired up properly. (Comment-out stuff you want to save, instead of delete.) It's worth a try, but, like I said, it sounds like there might be an issue in the code we can't see, since it works at least once.

Comment: @wazz I tried your suggestion but to no avail. When you say it might be an issue outside of the code, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the onclick event in the html markup, that's how you wire it up.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnUserEditSave" onclick="btnUserEditSave_Click" runat="server" Text="Save User" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="button saveButton xbtnWaitEvent" width="100px" ToolTip="Save changes" />
```

Comment: The addition of adding the onclick doesn't fix it. I don't think the issue lies with that though, considering the button itself does work but only the first time it saves the details.

Comment: does the click event on the SERVER side get fired? Show us that eventcode. Also when adding the onlick from the markup, let intellisense help you, e.g as you type  "on.." it should list out the events you can use, from there choose onclick.

Comment: when I debug it in the console I get "Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'default'." returned.

Comment: Can you share the whole page code? That error has nothing to do with the click code.

Comment: I could but the code is rather lengthy, is there anything in particular you want to have a look at?